# Repeat numbering sequence in excel using fill series

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't seem to find the exact answer I'm looking for anywhere, but I'm trying to create either a formula or figure out a way to have a numbered sequence auto fill in one column. The numbering would be 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 3.1 3.2... etc. The left handed number needs to grow but the right handed number only goes back and forth between 1 & 2.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the numbering starts on row 2, this formula should follow the pattern in your sample:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0) & "."&ISODD(ROW())+1
```

You will need to adjust the first or second value to accomodate formula sets starting on different rows

[image]

To start on row 10 use:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-8)/2,0) & "."&ISODD(ROW())+1
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly but I can't figure out which value needs to be changed since the 1.1 starts at F10. I keep playing with it but the starting number always comes back to 5.1 or an error message.

Comment: See the edit in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the `IF`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions. Assuming that `1.1` is in C1, enter the blow formula in C2:

```
=IF(INT(RIGHT(C1,1))=1,LEFT(C1) & "." & RIGHT(C1,1)+1,LEFT(C1)+1 & ".1")
```

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This one worked really well also but it only goes to 10.1 and then starts back at 1.1

Comment: @hana Change the formula to `=IF(INT(RIGHT(C1,1))=1,C1+0.1,C1+0.9)`. It will continue beyond 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine, start with 1.1 in the first cell (say B1) then formula in the next cell is:

`=B1+IF(ROUND(MOD(B1,1),1)=0.1,0.1,0.9)`

formula is just adding .1 or .9 to the number depending what the decimal portion is. As with other answers drag down as far as you need.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this formula in A1, then drag down as far as you need.

```
=ROUND(ROW(A1)/2,0)+IF(MOD(ROW(A1),2)=0,2,MOD(ROW(A1),2))/10
```

[image]